# Whats happens if you move a fraction into the denominator?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I have $(x^2 + 1) \frac{1}{3}(x^2 + 2)^{-2/3} (2x)$ and I see the solution is $ \frac{(1 + x^2) 2x}{3(2+x^2)^{2/3}}$. How come there is a $3$ on the bottom and not $1/3$? I thought a negative exponent indicated you moved the entire term into the denominator, but it appears like I am not understanding something about the way fractions or constants work here. What am I missing from my understanding?

Thanks!

Comment: $1/3$ is not in the exponent. It just multiplies everything; so you can put it on the bottom.

Comment: Ah okay, that makes sense. What if the 1/3 the term was expanded by 1/3 so it instead it was ((1/3)x^2 + 2/3)? Then would the fractions also be moved to the bottom?

Comment: Why did you put (2x) on the top?

Comment: (2x) was already on top, I just left it there. Why would I move it?

Comment: $2x$ indeed belongs on top.

Comment: from $\frac{1}{3}$ 1 is on top, 3 is in the bottom, What is the problem then? See the answer below.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

$$\frac 13\cdot (x^2 + 2)^{-2/3} = \dfrac 13\cdot\frac 1{(x^2 + 2)^{2/3}} = \dfrac 1{3(x^2 + 2)^{2/3}}$$